# Ways of marking changes being made to a file

Tags: version-control, file-systems

I am looking for a lightweight way to notate changes made to a file. The obvious answer to this is a version control system. But this is more robust than necessary for what I would like to do. All I want is the functionality to compare an edited file to its original in a lightweight manner.

Comment: well to me a _way to notate changes made to a file_, if (as you further specified it in comments to another answer) it is also _plug-able into larger software systems_ reads **version control** anyway

Comment: It's quite possible that there is no real alternative. Essentially, I'm looking for the functionality of comparing a file and comparing what would be 'forks' of that file.

Comment: Perhaps a bit obvious, but why wouldn't `diff` do what you need?

Comment: Could you clarify what you are looking for? Functionality for comparing "an edited file to its original" is available in many text editors. But, you must somehow get the original file first, and that is what version control is all about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to check the set of tools `diff`, `cmp`, `sdiff`, `diff3`, etc. These will provide you with easy to parse text output, making them usable from another program. [diff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) in particular would probably do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

For a complete list of text/source editors that produce "Diffs" see:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625/best-diff-tool

I would suggest using Meld if you are on Linux, and Netbeans if you aren't.  Both compare files in a graphical way.  Netbeans does Realtime-Data-Protection...  If you are interested in that... (It keeps track of all of your file-changes and allows you to compare any two versions for the last N* days)

Answer (score 1):

I just use notepad++. It has an on-the-fly style diff feature -- no versioning system required, and software is very lightweight.

Comment: If you want to check it out open N++ and open two "views" - on the left your old version and on the right the new one. Then go to Plugins -> Compare -> Compare.

Comment: To be clear I'm looking for solutions that are plug-able into larger software systems.

Comment: Ah. Cvs is my choice for larger projects, but if you don't want a version control then I'm not too sure what else to suggest.

Comment: Is it more "lightweight" than just a plain `diff` tool? I guess not.

Answer (score 1):

Are you after a code review tool. Give you use GIT, have a look at Gerrit. Even if you don't want code review, it may provide what you are seeking.

Answer (score 1):

`diff` is the answer to your explicit question.  But there's an implicit question as well.  You appear to think version control is heavyweight.  Some VCSes are indeed painful enough to get set up or deal with ongoing that there's a minimum threshold to get started with them.  Mercurial, however, works very easily and very nicely in a lightweight, no-server-needed, mode.

Comment: +1 for [Mercurial](http://hginit.com)

Comment: fair enough. heavy vs. lightweight wasn't so much my concern as functionality needed vs. not needed.

Answer (score 0):

Many text editors have this functionality built-in. Emacs is one example. If you set

```
(setq version-control t)
```

it will keep numbered backup files around. For a file named `foo`, Emacs will then create `foo.i` for integers `i`. By default, Emacs will keep the two oldest and two newest versions around, but this can of course be configured, just like everything else in Emacs can be configured :-)